# How do I use session variables within a SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Here is my relevant code:

```
<?php
 require("common.php");

 $userID = $_SESSION['user']['id'];

echo $userID;
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    if(empty($_POST['bio'])) 
        { 
            die("Please enter your Bio."); 
        }

    if(empty($_POST['location'])) 
        { 
            die("Please enter your location");      
        }  


    $query = 'UPDATE users
              SET usertype = 1
              WHERE id="$userID"';


    $query_params = array( 
        ':bio' => $_POST['bio'],
        ':location' => $_POST['location'], 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute(); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    {   
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    }

    // header("Location: myprofile.php");
} 
?>
```

I'm trying to update the field usertype to 1 on submission of a form, where the id matches that of the current session, as set in the variable $userID. When the code runs, it provides no errors, but utilizing a PHP variable inside of the query doesn't seem to work, the field doesn't update.

I've tried different quotes, and I can access the variable all throughout the multiple if statements, but not within the query. Also, I'm using PDO for this.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong quotes in your query. Change them to this:

```
$query = "UPDATE users
          SET usertype = 1
          WHERE id='$userID'";
```

The quotes are used when you want to pass a variable to the string without concatenating it. And MYSQL needs the apostrophes to understand the value as a string.

That's where you went wrong: you were using quotes `"` in the query.

Since you're already using PDO, so I don't see any problem on just passing the user id as a parameter:

```
$query = 'UPDATE users
          SET usertype = 1
          WHERE id=:userid';


$query_params = array( 
    ':bio' => $_POST['bio'],            //I think you will need to add those
    ':location' => $_POST['location'],  //parameters to the string or it will fail
    ':userid' => $userID
);
```

Of course, you can use the PHP string with apostrophes, but you would need to escape the apostrophes for the mysql query, and concatenate the variable, as follows:

```
$query = 'UPDATE users
          SET usertype = 1
          WHERE id=\''.$userID.'\'';
```